# Webpage Display Inaccuracy

Tags: html, css

```css
*{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
} 
div {
} 
h2{
} 
p { 
    width: 30%; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 20px; 
} 
#p1 { 
    background-color: green; 
} 
#p2 { 
    background-color: red; 
} 
#p3 { 
    background-color: orange; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Assignmet Solution to Module 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div>
  <p id="p1"> <h2>Burgers</h2>  A hamburger is a sandwich consisting of one or more cooked patties of ground meat, usually beef, placed inside a sliced bread roll or bun. The patty may be pan fried, grilled, smoked or flame broiled.</p>
  <p id="p2"> <h2>Fries</h2>  French fries, or simply fries, chips, finger chips, or French-fried potatoes, are batonnet or allumette-cut deep-fried potatoes.</p>
  <p id="p3"> <h2>Shakes</h2>  A milkshake, or simply shake, is a drink that is usually made by blending milk, ice cream, and flavorings or sweeteners such as butterscotch, caramel sauce, chocolate syrup, fruit syrup, or whole fruit into a thick, sweet, cold mixture.</p>
  
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

code here

I wanted to make three separate sections which would be placed as shown in the image but I seem to have messed up. I"ll be really grateful if you looked at it and help me solve this.

[This is how it was supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybhlj.png)

Comment: please share your CSS as well, and try and keep the amount of code to as little as necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'd imagine the problem is somewhere inside `style.css`. I'd help a lot if we could see the relevant parts of its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of smallish issues I can see with your code which could be messing the elements up a little bit:

1. You can't put `h2` elements inside `p` elements. This means that, when there is a `h2` opening tag, it automatically ends the `p` tag, which is...erm...interesting? Consider using a `div` tag instead.
2. You should set the `id` for the h2 tags, so they get the red background, not everything inside the `div` element.
3. You should then `float: right` these elements

```css
*{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
h2{
    float: right;
} 
div:not(#container) { 
    width: 30%; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 20px; 
} 
#p1 { 
    background-color: green; 
} 
#p2 { 
    background-color: red; 
} 
#p3 { 
    background-color: orange; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Assignmet Solution to Module 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div id="container">
  <div> <h2 id="p1">Burgers</h2>  A hamburger is a sandwich consisting of one or more cooked patties of ground meat, usually beef, placed inside a sliced bread roll or bun. The patty may be pan fried, grilled, smoked or flame broiled.</div>
  <div> <h2 id="p2">Fries</h2>  French fries, or simply fries, chips, finger chips, or French-fried potatoes, are batonnet or allumette-cut deep-fried potatoes.</div>
  <div> <h2 id="p3">Shakes</h2>  A milkshake, or simply shake, is a drink that is usually made by blending milk, ice cream, and flavorings or sweeteners such as butterscotch, caramel sauce, chocolate syrup, fruit syrup, or whole fruit into a thick, sweet, cold mixture.</div>
  
</div>


</body>
</html>
```